# add outlet programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, nsarray, iboutlet

In Interface Builder it is easy to connect an object from the NIB to an outlet in the File's Owner

I have an array of UIImage 
I need to create an outlet for each image of the array programmatically?

Thanks

Comment: If you're doing this programmatically, can you describe why you need an outlet for each item in the array?  What do you hope to perform with each of those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need `IBOutlet` entries for those controls you create in IB, Interface Builder. If you create controls programmatically, which it sounds like you want to do, you go ahead and programmatically create your `UIImageView` objects, but you would not have not corresponding `IBOutlet` statements.

Google "UIImageView create programmatically" for some examples.